# Why my object's extrude is not the same as in tutorial's one in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I follow this tutorial, when I follow his steps, I get this result [image]

Meanwhile, here is his result [image]

I don't know what making this wrong, I am sure I follow his step by step to this point. Why can this be happening?

Here is my file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ncgBV8tIlI1O-FTxmqwnPgauUqte7U-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was tested using Inkscape 1.2.  It seems to work as expected.  Here are the steps.

1. Type something
2. *Path > Object to Path*
3. *Object > Ungroup*
4. *Path > Combine*
5. *Edit > Duplicate*, and set the fill of the top duplicate to something else so you can see it
6. Move the top letters to offset them
7. Select both paths, and do *Extensions > Generate from Path > Extrude*

Here's the result

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but by following your Path > Combine make a difference, check this file out, here I compare by using Path > Union and by Path > Combine                                     Path>Union https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GI9Ugpanrt33WjViRtRsuFZxSVCurO4J/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                      Path> Combine  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l6IhLITfHs6PGqv8S1DlolnuvGK49KRY/view?usp=sharing      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s9DCb7UCQSz42kh3Ykj5ltKh93R6orSr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @EarvinWilliams Don't use Path > Union.  It won't work in all cases. Combine and Union are not the same operation.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will careful  for next project path operation

Answer (score 0):

You tried to generate an extrusion between 2 combined paths which both contain outline curves of letters I, N and K.

The result is a mess if Inkscape cannot decide right the node correspondence relation between the upper and lower INKs. To get it surely right make at first the lower combined path. Duplicate it and use the duplicate as the upper combined path. This guarantees the identical node order. Randomly collected subpaths very likely have random node order differences for ex. depending on their layering order before making the combined path.

Before applying the extrusion you can move, scale and rotate both inks as needed.

Comment: I am sure the lower and upper combined path are the same in my file and in image of mine above, so they must have identical node order